# Error when run program in jvm 18: Java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, java-runtime-compiler

i'm trying to run a project from *Spring Initializr* and I am getting the error `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` when I try to run the Main. The complete error is `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 62.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0`. The gradle is set to `jvmTarget = 18` but aparrently when I put it to `11` it seem to fix the problem. I want to know why when I downgrade the version the program work.

Comment: Seems you execute programs with JDK version lower than version used for build.

Comment: The problem is than 18 > 11 but 11 works and 18 not.

Comment: which version of gradle are you using ?
`https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html`

Comment: I'm using gradle version 7.5. Which is compatible with java 18.

Comment: which JDK are you using in your IDE ? In your global settings ? And in your project structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error shows that you use older JRE version to run than to build. Your setup in gradle, you have to check what is your runtime version.

It seems you use IntelliJ.
Go to File > Project Structure > Project > SDK - check if you have the Java 18 set here. You can also check in Run Configuration if there is proper JVM set.

Check also the JAVA_HOME env variable and set this variable to point to your recent JDK.

Comment: I had 3 directories, 1.8 18 and jbr-11, I change the path of jbr-11 to the path of jdk 18 and it fix the problem! But thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the problem, I had to change the jetbrains runtime in project structure to the jdk 18 path. Aparently it fix the problem.